# Basic Model of a F# program using MySQL

Tags: mysql, f#

Just starting to experiment with F#.  I have this code working in C#:

```
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.IO;

namespace SandboxExecuteReader
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection();
            MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand();
            if (!SQLdbOpen(myConnection, myCommand)) return;
            DoWork(myCommand);
            myConnection.Close();
            return;
        }

        private static void DoWork(MySqlCommand myCommand)
        {
            myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM xxx.mytable";
            using (var reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    string Field1 = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Field1"));
                    string Field2 = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Field2"));
                    string Field3 = reader.GetString(reader.GetOrdinal("Field3"));
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", Field1, Field2, Field3);
                }
            }
        }

        private static bool SQLdbOpen(MySqlConnection myConnection, MySqlCommand myCommand)
        {
            /* 
            * Open Connection to SQL DB
            */

            string ConnectionString = "server=(someIP); uid=Me; password=MyPass";

            try
            {
                myConnection.ConnectionString = ConnectionString;
                myConnection.Open();
                myCommand.Connection = myConnection;
            }
            catch (MySqlException E)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Open Error: {0}", E.Message);
                Console.WriteLine("Press RETURN to continue or CONTROL-C to abort");
                Console.ReadLine();
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Questions:

1. In C#, I add a reference to MySql.Data.dll.  How do I do that in F#?
2. There seems to be something about #r ... where does that line go?  Somewhere in the .fsproj file?
3. How would this code look in F#?

Comment: The preferred format for questions on stack overflow is [one question per post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/222735), so you might want to break that down into multiple questions.   For #1 and #2 see maybe [F# error 'error FS0039: The namespace or module 'MySql' is not defined'?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4906663), [Having trouble configuring SQLProvider in F# with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38416321) or [F# Connect to Online MySQL DB execute query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37415001).

Comment: Thanks.  Lets start with the most pressing question -- How do you get F# to recognize MySql.Data.dll?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first thing you need to decide is whether you are going to run this as a standalone script (`.fsx` file) or a project (consisting of `.fs` source files and a `.fsproj` project file).

If this is going to be a project, it works just like a C# project: you add a reference to `MySql.Data.dll` in your `.fsproj` file. If you're using Visual Studio, you can right-click on the project and find `MySql.Data` in NuGet via the "Manage NuGet Packages..." menu item.

If it's going to be a standalone script, you can add a NuGet reference to MySql by placing this line at the very top: `#r "nuget: MySql.Data"`.

Converting your code from C# is a bit more involved, but your `main` function might look like this (assuming this is a `.fs` file):

```
open MySql.Data.MySqlClient

let sQLdbOpen (myConnection : MySqlConnection) (myCommand : MySqlCommand) =
    // ...
    true

let doWork (myCommand : MySqlCommand) =
    // ...
    ()

[<EntryPoint>]
let main args =
    use myConnection = new MySqlConnection()
    use myCommand = new MySqlCommand()
    if sQLdbOpen myConnection myCommand then
        doWork myCommand
        myConnection.Close()
    0
```

(Caveat: I did this translation by eye, so it might not be exactly right.)

Comment: Thank you for that info.  Helpful!  For some reason, when I create a project in VS2019, in the solution explorer, there isn't a "references" section.  Your suggestions got me to explore further and I found Project --> Add Project Reference allowed me to add "open MySql.Data.MySqlClient" at the top of the program.  However, program still does not know MySqlConnection and MySqlCommand, which under C# it would have known with the similar using statement.  Where is MySqlConnection and MySqlCommand?  Thanks!

Comment: Are you using .NET Core or .NET Framework?

Comment: I am using .NET Core

Comment: OK. You should be able to see "Dependencies" >> "Packages" >> "MySql.Data" in the Solution Explorer.

Comment: For the .NET Core, even though I added MySql.Data using Project --> Add Project Reference, it does not show up on the Solution Explorer Dependencies >> Packages.  Also, Dependencies >> COM has a yellow-triangle-! under the COM item, then again under {bee4bfec......}

Comment: I tried it under .NET Framework and that seems to be working better.  Need to recode my C# to F# to fully test it there.

Comment: Hmm, I’m not sure what the issue was. Managing packages in Visual Studio should be nearly identical for C# and F# projects, but it sounds like you’ve worked it out. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Still struggling with both the .NET Framework and the .NET Core.  The Framework seems to be closer to working.  The program compiles but before doing anything gets the error "Entry point must be static."  The program starts with type Class1() = 
    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main argv =
        use myConnection = new MySqlConnection()

Comment: Imagine returns after the first 2 "=" and the "]"

Comment: You don't need `type Class1() =`. For starters, just use the exact code I posted above and see if you can get it to compile.

Comment: Note: I updated my code slightly to make sure it compiles cleanly.

Comment: In the .NET Core model, my first line is "open System" and there is a red squiggle under the "o".  The error is FS1108:  The type 'ConfigurationElement' is required here and is unavailable.  You must add a reference to assembly 'system.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, Version 4.0.3.0 ...

Comment: If your .NET Core code uses `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager`, then you need to download it from NuGet, just like you did with `MySql.Data`. (Note: This is true for C# projects as well.)

Comment: Is your example for .NET Core or .NET Framework?  In CORE I can't get it to recognize MySqlConnection and MySqlCommand even though MySql.Data is one of the Assemblies.  In FRAMEWORK, it wants that type Class1()...

Comment: I'm using .NET Core. I've created a GitHub repository for you as a template [here](https://github.com/brianberns/MySqlTest). You should be able to clone this repo and then build it cleanly in Visual Studio.

Comment: FWIW, the actual F# code should be virtually identical in Core vs. Framework. The differences are in the project configuration. Framework doesn't require `type Class1()`.

Comment: I had not brought MySql.Data in with NuGet, that was my problem.  In C#, I have been able to add a reference to it without doing the NuGet thing.  I deleted the whole directory tree and started from scratch (keeping my code of course).  With NuGet for both MySql.Data and System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager, it now compiles and runs.  New problem:  myConnection.Open() works, but myCommand.Connection = myConnection does not.  I get a green squiggle under that, and if I change it to let result = myCommand.Connection = myConnection, the result is false.

Comment: In F#, most values are immutable. If you want to assign to a mutable variable, you have to use `<-`, not `=`, so that line should be `myCommand.Connection <- myConnection`. As you learn F#, you should try to avoid such assignments, though. The `=` sign is used for `let` bindings and for equality comparison.

Comment: Thank you!!!!   That was the magic I needed.  I'd be glad to share my code with you, is there a way to do that?

Comment: Easiest way is put your code in a GitHub repository, which is very easy from recent versions of VS. Right click on the solution in Solution Explorer and choose "Create Git Repository...".

Comment: BTW, if you can accept this answer so it stops appearing as unsolved, it would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Done.  See:  https://github.com/MarkRLV/FortranSQL/

Comment: I'm getting a 404 error. Make sure the repo is public.

Comment: Changed to public.

Comment: I've got a local copy. Happy to help if you run into further issues.